# Any way to know if a guid looks like a "normal" guid with characters and number?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, guid

I am converting a string to a guid to check if the string is a valid guid , in c# .net 4.0
The string is :

`string guid = "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111";`

This guid should be invalid for me , even though it have as many characters as a guid have. Is there a way to check if a guid looks like a "normal" guid with different chars and numbers?

All these methods dont work because they return the guid is valid for me.

```
Guid.Parse

Guid.TryParse

Guid.TryParseExact
```

Thank you!

EDIT :

To clarify, i need to check if my guid is like these Guids : dc6a1ad8-4743-4487-a28e-54d31870dfcb

We can discard the word "invalid" and "valid" because people seem to focus a bit on that. So i need make sure a guid looks more like this : dc6a1ad8-4743-4487-a28e-54d31870dfcb instead of this : 11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111

Comment: Ok, so what's your custom logic that tells you that it's not valid GUID? It's pretty valid.

Comment: You first need to define what a valid GUID is for you.

Comment: The string is a _valid_ GUID string. What makes you think it should be invalid?

Comment: First you have to define what you mean by 'valid', if you are not accepting the standard definition.

Comment: @Oded he means that the letters are not "random looking" enough for him to think it's a valid GUID

Comment: Yes I would say that your example is an very unusual GUID (in that it seems uniform from a human perspective) but it is a valid GUID.

Comment: @Esailija - That's not the question though... `Guid.Empty` returns a valid GUID instance that is composed of all `0`s.

Comment: There's a problem with the human brain and randomness -> they dont fit! 123456789 is (created by a RNG) as random as 6481286412 and as 111111111. The first and third number LOOK less random, because your brain always tries to find a reason/meaning/pattern.

Comment: @Oded Yes we all know it's a valid guid, but I was just trying to clarify why **he** doesn't think it's a "valid" guid - because it does not look "random enough" by human perception

Comment: This is a valid guid for me : dc6a1ad8-4743-4487-a28e-54d31870dfcb

Comment: @syncis And what's the difference to the one in the question, except the different digits?

Comment: @Daniel, The first one is created manually, the other one is created my Guid.NewGuid

Comment: So this comes down to *How do I check whether a string consists of valid hex numbers and does contain letters and numbers*?

Comment: @syncis: You need to understand that both have a valid GUID format. You need to define the criteria that you want to apply to differentiate between "valid" and "invalid" GUIDs as all of them are valid. A GUID is basically just a 16 byte number, most of the time expressed in HEX - nothing more. What makes GUID special is the algorithm that creates them in a way that makes collisions nearly impossible. However, you can't really check a GUID after it has been created and determine whether it has been created by hand or by such an algorithm.

Comment: Run Guid.NewGuid for a million (or so) years and one of the GUIDs will be 11111.... (another one will be the birthday of your mother). BTW does this lead anywhere? You can not check if a GUID is "real". Period.

Comment: Why does people rage because of a question? god......

Comment: Please do not vandalize your own posts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to check whether the `Guid` has different characters, you can check the number of distinct bytes it contains:

```
int count = yourGuid.ToByteArray().Distinct().Count();
```

For `Guid.Empty` or `11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111`, the result will be `1`.
For `dc6a1ad8-4743-4487-a28e-54d31870dfcb`, the result is `16`.

You'll just need to decide how large the number needs to be for you to accept the `Guid` as "normal".

Comment: @syncis: Honestly, that's nonsense.

Comment: 12345678-ABCD-ABCD-ABCD-ABCD-123456789012 - looks "fake" and will pass the test. BTW: by sorting out "strange" GUIDs, you loose quit some bit of randomness!

Comment: @igrimpe: `12345678-ABCD-ABCD-ABCD-123456789012` returns `7`. As I said, it's a matter of deciding which number is high enough to consider the `Guid` to be "normal", which obviously depends on the definition of "normal".

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: I'm not saying it's a particularly sensible thing to do; I'm just answering the question! :)

Comment: @igrimpe some people here, like DanielHilgarth dont seem to understand my definition of a "normal" guid even though i explained that i needed it to be that way for a specific scenario

Comment: @syncis: You didn't specify what you see as a "normal" GUID. That's what others and I are trying to tell you.

Comment: @RichardDeeming: I know. My comment was meant for syncis, not for you :-)